# What is the meaning of this word “function”?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I saw this text in a picture on social media, but I don’t know what the meaning of “function” is here, I’ve tried some dictionaries but couldn’t find what I was looking for.

> You get to invite 1
> person to a function.
> If they're late you win
> $1,000,000 who you
> inviting?

Answer (score 1):

It means a party or event. From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/function):

> an official ceremony or a formal social event, such as a party or a special meal, at which a lot of people are usually present:

Comment: Also [Merriam-Webster 4](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/function) and [Oxford 4](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/function).

Comment: So general reference, not suitable for asking _or answering_ on ELU.